# Read and write pdf file with some images in wp8 use of PdfSharp-WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application. In my application I am successfully able to add reference of PdfSharp-WP7.Now I want to create a new pdf file with some images and text and save it locally And I want to display/Read the data after successfully creation of file. Please share with some code, or any link to take a start with.

**Note** : I am not looking for launcher apps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code written yet? Did you read the PdfSharp documentation?

Comment: Here is the similar thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372260/create-pdfs-with-images-in-wp8

Comment: @NayeemMansoori there are three different kind if links. css, javascript and componenet

Comment: send css component..............

Answer (score 0):

As per the notes on the home page of the project it is a port of PDFsharp and you should look there for docs.

The hello world smaple can be found at http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample.ashx and looks a bit like this:

```
  // Create a new PDF document
  PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
  document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

  // Create an empty page
  PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

  // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
  XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

  // Create a font
  XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

  // Draw the text
  gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
    new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
    XStringFormats.Center);

  // Save the document...
  const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
  document.Save(filename);
```

Comment: -I tried using this code but gfx.DrawString("Hello,World!", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),XStringFormats.Center); gave me an exception with message="Cannot allocate font data.". Also, lease let me know what document.Save(filename) does? and what if I want to save the pdf into IsolatedStorage?