# Create PDFs with Images in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am making an app in which I want to create pdfs out of the images I store in the Isolated storage. Many opensource libraries are available for solving the purpose but unfortunately none expresses their comparability with windows phone 8.

then I came across [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx)

the post explains about writing the pdf file  by making the pdf header. But, this only creates a pdf with some      text written in it. I, now want to add some images in it. How shall I proceed for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. These are the links which would be very much helpful if you are looking to make a pff
with text and images without the usage of opensource libraries.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18623/Add-Images-and-Textboxes-to-PDF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7627/PDF-Library-for-creating-PDF-with-tables-and-text

Comment: Can you please post the code, because I am facing the same problem. Please help me. @A.K.

Comment: I have to create PDF with images in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, and I am stuck here. Thanks!! @A.K.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Imaging%5Fmodel

Understanding the PDF file format – how are images stored
http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/04/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-how-are-images-stored/

Check the above links. They might be helpful.