# Converting VB code to C# for use in pdf generation

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, windows-phone-8, pdf-generation

I have a requirement to generate a document in pdf file format in a Windows Phone 8. While researching, I came across  [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx). I copied the source code (written in VB) and converted it to C#. The challenge I am now facing is the C# equivalent of this VB code

`stream.Write({&HC7, &HEC, &H8F, &HA2}, 0, 4)`

which i translated to `stream.Write({0xc7, 0xec, 0x8f, 0xa2}, 0, 4)` in C#.

The problem now is my C# equivalent seems to be wrong as the compiler keeps throwing error.

Does anyone know the exact equivalent of the VB code in C#? Is there another better way to achieve same? The pdf does not need to contain an image.

Comment: Can you show error message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372260/create-pdfs-with-images-in-wp8, just if you are looking for a way that is much more organised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding **new byte[]**

```
stream.Write(new byte[]{0xc7, 0xec, 0x8f, 0xa2}, 0, 4)
```

You can initialize a new array by using the {} notation, but you can't pass it directly as a parameter.