# how to generate a pdf from a windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pdf

I am building an application in windows phone 7 application. I have a form in my application. The code for the form is:

XAML:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="6" Height="74" Name="name" Text="*Name" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus1" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="66" Height="74" Name="age" Text="*Age" Width="453" BorderThickness="0" />
<TextBlock Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="157" Height="44" Name="gen" Text="Gender" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" Width="134" />
<RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="157" FontStyle="Italic" GroupName="Gender" Foreground="Black" Content="Male" Height="71" Name="male" Width="154" />
<RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="207"  FontStyle="Italic" GroupName="Gender" Foreground="Black" Content="Female" Height="71" Name="fem" Width="140" />
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus2" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="267" Height="74" Name="sadd" Text="*Street Address" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus3" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="327" Height="74" Name="cadd" Text="*City Address" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus4" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="387" Height="74" Name="eadd" Text="*Email Address" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus5" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="447" Height="74" Name="phn" Text="*Phone" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus6" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="507" Height="74" Name="zip" Text="*Zip Code" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Now on clicking the submit button i want to generate a pdf which should contain the data i have entered in the form along with some manual data. The generated pdf should be sent like an attachment in an email and after that the data should be submitted in a particular web method which is "registertoteam". Can anyone please help me with codes on how to do this. My cs file at present looks like this:

```
namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
public partial class Join : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Join()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }


    private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text.Equals("*Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            name.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (age.Text.Equals("*Age", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            age.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sadd.Text.Equals("*Street Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            sadd.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cadd.Text.Equals("*City Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            cadd.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (eadd.Text.Equals("*Email Address", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            eadd.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (phn.Text.Equals("*Phone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            phn.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void OnGotFocus6(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (zip.Text.Equals("*Zip Code", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            zip.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }


    private void Image_Previous(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AAP.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
        }

        if (age.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the age");
            age.Focus();
        }

        if (male.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string gender = male.Content.ToString();
        }
        else if (fem.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string gender = fem.Content.ToString();
        }
        else    //none of them is selected.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select your Gender");
        }

        if (sadd.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Street Address");
            sadd.Focus();
        }

        if (cadd.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the City Address");
            cadd.Focus();
        }

        if (eadd.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Email Address");
            eadd.Focus();
        }

        if (phn.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Phone Number");
            phn.Focus();
        }

        if (zip.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Zipcode");
            zip.Focus();
        }

 }

    private void reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        name.Text = String.Empty;
        age.Text = String.Empty;
        sadd.Text = String.Empty;
        cadd.Text = String.Empty;
        eadd.Text = String.Empty;
        phn.Text = String.Empty;
        zip.Text = String.Empty;
        male.IsChecked = false;
        fem.IsChecked = false;

    }
}
```

}

I know how to add my web service and how to get data from web service and display it in my application. Now i want to send these data to webmethod which is registertoteam. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I integrated the same in one of my apps recently. And I came up with the following decisions

The open source libraries provided by codeplex are of no worth. They don't even get added to the project.

Currently, there is no support or any library availbale for a windows phone developer to render pdfs using it.

Its would be a bit tedious task. As for making a pdf you would need to make the complete pdf file format by yourselves as there is no library support.

so doing it in the core [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx) is the first link I am gonna recommend.(This solves your purpose.). This Link has a source code attached as well.

for more and well organised solutions check my stackover flow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372260/create-pdfs-with-images-in-wp8) regarding the same.

And regarding the email attachment its My and your Bad! Till now there is no such support to a developer. :(

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. Can you help me with sending the data from the form to a particular web method on clciking the submit button. The web method to which i want to send data is registertoteam

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to share code currently but quick googling with bing give me below results http://pdfsharpwp7.codeplex.com/ and http://itextsharpsl.codeplex.com/ (Recommended).

Comment: Will u be able to share codes later. Or if the code for pdf generation is too lengthy can u just write code to send data to the registertoteam webmethod on clicking the submit button

Comment: The web method regitertoteam contains the following data:              name, street_address, city_address, zip_code, email_address,phone_no, age, gender

Comment: I will be able to sitdown on it tommorow evening.